# Why does CO2 only exist in gaseous and solid state under STP/SATP?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, phase, covalent-compounds, sublimation

Why does carbon dioxide only exist in gas and solid state under STP/SATP conditions?

$\ce{CO2}$ pressurized to $\pu{5.1 atm}$ can exist in all 3 states: solid, gas, and liquid.

However, why couldn't the same happen in 1atm pressure? As a solid chunk of dry ice is the coldest you could get $\ce{CO2}$, why cant you warm it up slightly but still have it cold enough to turn into a liquid, instead of directly to a gas?

Comment: Because its pressure at triple point is higher then atmospheric.